# Indexing an array with duplicate elements before and after sorting

Tags: ruby, algorithm

This is the basic problem: I have an array of integers with possibly duplicate elements. I need to know the indices of each element, but when I sort the array, whenever I select an element from the new array, I want to be able to reference the same element from the original array.

I am looking for a solution to the problem, or maybe a solution to the approach I am taking.

Here is an array

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 2]
```

There are two 2's and two 3's, but if I'm working with the first `2` (from the left), I want to work with index 1, and if I'm working with the second `2`, I want to be working with index 6. So I use a helper array to allow me to do this:

```
helper = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

Which I will iterate over and use to access each element from `a`.
I could have accomplished this with `each_with_index`, but the problem begins when I sort the array.

Now I have a sort order

```
sort_order = [2, 4, 1, 5, 3]
```

I use `sort_by` to sort `a` according to sort_order, to produce

```
sorted_a = [2, 2, 4, 1, 5, 3, 3]
```

You may assume all elements in the input exist in `sort_order` to avoid `sort_by` exceptions.

Now the problem is that my `helper` array should be updated to match the new positions. Each element should be sorted the same way as `a` was sorted, because it is unclear whether the first 2 in the new array was at index 1 or at index 6 of the original array.

So my new helper array might look like

```
new_helper = [1, 6, 3, 0, 5, 2, 4]
```

So if I were to go with this approach, how would I produce the `new_helper` array, given the original array and the sort order?

Maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Does it matter if the helper array points to a different element from the original as long as the value of that element is the same ?

Comment: The values are not important (in the context of my methods that are using them), but the positions are. That's what I had in mind when I created my helper array, so the new helper array should point to the same element.

Comment: You need to implement the sorting logic yourself then, and whenever you swap a position in your array swap it also inside of your helper array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a list of pairs of the original data and that data's index.  Like this:

```
a = [(1, 0), (2, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (3, 4), (5, 5), (2,6)]
```

Sort that list (lexicographically, or just ignore the second part of the pair except to carry it along).  The second item in every pair tells you where the element was in the original array.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest first zip the original array with the helper array, sort the zipped array according the component coming from the original array, then unzip them (this method does not exist unfortunately, but you can do transpose). Or you can implement your own sorting logic as pointed out by Hunter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to swap the values in the helper array when you swap then in your main array.

```
loop do
   swapped = false
   0.upto(list.size-2) do |i|
      if list[i] > list[i+1]
         list[i], list[i+1] = list[i+1], list[i] # swap values
         helper[i], helper[i+1] = helper[i+1], helper[i]; #swap helper values
         swapped = true
      end
   end
   break unless swapped
end
```

**Example**

```
irb(main):001:0> def parallel_sort(list, helper)
irb(main):002:1> loop do
irb(main):003:2*    swapped = false
irb(main):004:2>    0.upto(list.size-2) do |i|
irb(main):005:3*       if list[i] > list[i+1]
irb(main):006:4>          list[i], list[i+1] = list[i+1], list[i] # swap values
irb(main):007:4>          helper[i], helper[i+1] = helper[i+1], helper[i]; #swap helper values
irb(main):008:4*          swapped = true
irb(main):009:4>       end
irb(main):010:3>    end
irb(main):011:2>    break unless swapped
irb(main):012:2> end
irb(main):013:1> return [list, helper]
irb(main):014:1> end
=> nil
irb(main):015:0> a = [3,2,1]
=> [3, 2, 1]
irb(main):016:0> b = ["three","two","one"]
=> ["three", "two", "one"]
irb(main):017:0> parallel_sort(a,b)
=> [[1, 2, 3], ["one", "two", "three"]]
irb(main):018:0>
```

Comment: The sort order is based on the custom sort order array though, and I'm not sure how to implement that kind of sorting efficiently. But the idea works. I was hoping to just use `sort_by` to get things done for me.

Comment: @Keikoku Well as long as you aren't sorting hundreds of thousands of elements; what I posted above you do fine.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting inside a loop is rarely a good idea.... If you are doing so, you might be better off with a treap (fast on average but infrequently an operation will take a while) or red-black tree (relatively slow, but gives pretty consistent operation times).  These are rather like hash tables, except they're not as fast, and they keep elements stored in order using trees.

Either way, why not use a class that saves both the value to sort by, and the helper value?  Then they're always together, and you don't need a custom sorting algorithm.

Comment: Yes that's the solution I was going towards since the original design is pretty bad. But I imagine someone might run into this kind of problem at some point where they don't have the option of changing the design.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have `sort_order`, your array is already kind of sorted, so we should use this fact as an advantage. I came up with this simple solution:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 5, 2]
sort_order = [2, 4, 1, 5, 3]

# Save indices
indices = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = [] }
a.each_with_index { |elem, index| indices[elem] << index }

# Sort the array by placing elements into "right" positions
sorted = []
helper = []
sort_order.each do |elem|
  indices[elem].each do |index|
    sorted << elem
    helper << index
  end
end

p sorted
p helper
```

The algorithm is based on idea of [Counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort), I slightly modified it to save indices.